# MongoDB 3.4 Sharding Error. "Cannot accept sharding commands if not started with --shardsvr"

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have installed mongoDB 3.4.5 in centOS 7.2 machine.
I am configuring sharding in standalone mode.

Steps I followed:

For Replica Sets:

```
mongod --replSet rs0 --dbpath /data/srd/rs0 --logpath /data/srd/rs0/log.rs0 --port 27000 --fork --logappend --smallfiles --oplogSize 50 &
mongod --replSet rs0 --dbpath /data/srd/rs1 --logpath /data/srd/rs1/log.rs1 --port 27001 --fork --logappend --smallfiles --oplogSize 50 &
mongod --replSet rs0 --dbpath /data/srd/rs2 --logpath /data/srd/rs2/log.rs2 --port 27002 --fork --logappend --smallfiles --oplogSize 50 &
```

For Shards:

```
mongod --replSet rs0 --shardsvr --dbpath /data/srd/srd0 --logpath /data/srd/srd0/log.srd0 --port 27020 --fork --logappend --smallfiles --oplogSize 50 &
mongod --replSet rs0 --shardsvr --dbpath /data/srd/srd1 --logpath /data/srd/srd1/log.srd1 --port 27021 --fork --logappend --smallfiles --oplogSize 50 &
mongod --replSet rs0 --shardsvr --dbpath /data/srd/srd2 --logpath /data/srd/srd2/log.srd2 --port 27022 --fork --logappend --smallfiles --oplogSize 50 &
```

For Config server:

```
mongod --configsvr --replSet configReplSet --dbpath /data/srd/cfgrep0 --logpath /data/srd/cfgrep0/log.cfgrep0 --port 27006 --fork &
mongod --configsvr --replSet configReplSet --dbpath /data/srd/cfgrep1 --logpath /data/srd/cfgrep1/log.cfgrep1 --port 27007 --fork &
mongod --configsvr --replSet configReplSet --dbpath /data/srd/cfgrep2 --logpath /data/srd/cfgrep2/log.cfgrep2 --port 27008 --fork &
```

To start Mongos:

```
mongos --configdb configReplSet/sit:27006,sit:27007,sit:27008 --port 26060
```

I am able to login the mongos shell and also able to add the shards.
But while enabling the shard I am getting exceptions as below.

```
mongos> sh.enableSharding("test");
{
        "code" : 193,
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Cannot accept sharding commands if not started with --shardsvr"
}
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: This question really belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com) which is the site to use for database administration and configuration questions. StackOverflow is for programming topics only, of which this question is not. Please move your question to the correct site by deleting and reposting.

Answer (score 3):

These are steps I followed to setup sharding: 
1. Start Config Server:

```
mongod --configsvr --dbpath fresh/config1 --port 30001 --replSet r1
```

2. Start Mongos:

   mongos --configdb "r1/localhost:30001" --port 40001
3. Connect to mongo shell and execute these commands:
   Connect to Mongo Shell :

   mongo --host localhost --port 30001

Now execute these commands:

```
rs.initiate();
rs.status();
```

4. Start Mongo Shard Servers:

   mongod --shardsvr --port 50001 --dbpath fresh/m1
   mongod --shardsvr --port 50002 --dbpath fresh/m2
5. Connect to mongos and execute these commands:
   Connect to mongos:

   mongo --host localhost --port 40001

Now execute below commands:

```
sh.addShard('localhost:50001');
sh.addShard('localhost:50002');
sh.enableSharding('testdb');
sh.shardCollection('testdb.demo',{'name':1});
```

MongoDB User Manual: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/#sharding